# UK Visa group appointment

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Could you advise how to book group appointments for UK visa for 50 people from Morocco?
I contcatced UKVI and was told to contact 'teleperformance' does it mean TLS centre?
I sent them an email 5 days ago but they never answer.
Thank you

Comment: Appointment for 50 people might require a prior visit by the representative to the TLS center to make special arrangements. Using the standard web channel I think it will be hard to book 50 slots together.

Comment: @Ouadie In which country will the applications be made? There are special arrangements for tour groups from China, for example https://www.gov.uk/ads-visa Otherwise you’ll probably need to arrange this via a travel agent

Comment: @Traveller Thank you for your answer. It's from Morocco